# ClientException while calling RegisterTaskDefinition operation: Invalid arn syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, elastic-container-registry

I try to execute following command with AWS CLI.

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://jenkins/task-definition.json
```

task-definition.json

```
{
    "family": "interactify-family",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::617346611291:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "backend",
            "image": "interactify:latest",
            "memory": 400,
            "dependsOn": [
                {"containerName": "backend-db", "condition": "START"},
                {"containerName": "backend-cache", "condition": "START"}
            ],
            "environmentFiles": [
                {"value": "s3://interactify-environment-files/dev.env", "type": "s3"}
            ],
            "environment": [
                {"name": "MYSQL_DB_NAME", "value": "interactify"},
                {"name": "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "value": "interactify.settings"}
            ],
            "mountPoints": [{"sourceVolume": "gunicorn", "containerPath": "/etc/gunicorn"}]
        },
        {
            "name": "backend-db",
            "memory": 200,
            "image": "mysql:latest",
            "environment": [
                {"name": "MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD", "value": "1"},
                {"name": "MYSQL_DATABASE", "value": "interactify"}
            ],
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "mysql-data",
                    "containerPath": "/var/lib/mysql"
                }
            ],
            "healthCheck": {
                "command": ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"],
                "interval": 10,
                "timeout": 20,
                "retries": 10
            }
        },
        {"image": "redis:latest", "name": "backend-cache", "memory": 100},
        {
            "name": "backend-server",
            "memory": 200,
            "image": "nginx:latest",
            "mountPoints": [{"sourceVolume": "nginx", "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/conf.d"}],
            "portMappings": [{"containerPort": 80, "hostPort": 80, "protocol": "tcp"}],
            "dependsOn": [{"containerName": "backend", "condition": "START"}]
        }
    ],
    "volumes": [
      {"name": "nginx", "host": {"sourcePath": "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/interactify/interactify/nginx"}},
      {"name": "mysql-data", "host": {"sourcePath": "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/interactify/interactify/mysql-data"}},
      {"name": "gunicorn", "host": {"sourcePath": "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/interactify/interactify/gunicorn"}}
    ]
}
```

Getting the following error:

An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the RegisterTaskDefinition operation: Invalid arn syntax.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.